# Directx 11 Compatiblilty

Tags: directx

My hardware only supports Directx 10.1 but I know through feature levels I can develop with the directx 11 API and still maintain compatibility. One concern that I have is my hardware supports shader model 4.1 and directx 11 supports shader model 5.0.

So my question is will I be able to develop for directx 11 including the shader model 5.0 with my directx 10.1 hardware?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can use the DX11 software rasterizer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx ). But I've never used it myself, so I can't really write an actual answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using the reference device or WARP, the answer is no.

While you will be using the DX11 API, you will have to create a 10.1 feature level device and consequently you won't be able to create shaders compiled with the 5.0 shader model level.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to upgrade to Windows 10 DirectX 11 is already installed on your machine but given that your machine can't support the newer shader model. I know this is blatantly obvious but if you want to develop in DirectX 11 then buy hardware that is compatible(most of the hardware that supports it is inexpensive and you might only have to upgrade your GPU). Or try looking online for drivers for your GPU that can add DirectX 11 to your GPU. Most GPUs made in the past 10 years support DirectX 11 you just have to download the newest driver. Those are the two simplest fixes that I can think of.

Comment: You answered a 7-year old question by referring to 10-year old hardware. That said, I think he will have had no problem developing Dx11 apps with Sm 4.0. The feature level settings will drop his shader compiler version to that of 10.1.