# DirectX 11 initialisation "works" and fails on rendering only

Tags: c#, compatibility, directx-11

Does anybody know why device creation for using DirectX11 works, even though the hardware doesn't support it? I have the following simplified code (this uses SlimDx, but I guess the language is of second importance here:

```
var form = frm;
form.Resize += form_Resize;
var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
{
    BufferCount = 1,
    ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
        IsWindowed = true,
        OutputHandle = form.Handle,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
        Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

    Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, desc, out device, out swapChain);
    device.Factory.SetWindowAssociation(form.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);
    Resize(form.ClientSize);

    sprite = new SpriteRendererSlimDx(device, m_lock);
    var textBlock = new TextBlockRendererSlimDx(sprite, "Arial", FontWeight.Bold, SlimDX.DirectWrite.FontStyle.Normal, FontStretch.Normal, 16);

    MessagePump.Run(form, () =>
    {
        device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.DarkBlue);
        textBlock.DrawString("Hello World", Vector2.Zero, Color.Red);
        sprite.Flush();
        swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
    });
```

The code opens a window and draws some text. It works fine on Graphics Cards supporting Feature Level 11.0, but if I run the same code on my aging ATI Radeon HD 4550, which only supports Feature Level 10.1, the device driver locks up and windows restarts the display driver.

The issue is not with the (in the example not shown) text rendering, but happens for rendering triangles, too. Debugging shows that the lockup happens on the swapChain.Present() call.

[Directx 11 Compatiblilty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890254/directx-11-compatiblilty) suggests that I might be having a problem with using Shader Level 5 (which I'm trying to use), but generally my question is: Why don't I get an ordinary error message if something is not supported? The driver shouldn't attempt to compile Shader Level 5, if the card cannot do it, should it?

*Update*
The error also seems to happen if I only use shader level 4.

Comment: If Windows resets the display driver, it's probably a driver bug and not anything to do with your code, especially if it works fine on other hardware.

Comment: @MooseBoys: I'm not really concerned that it doesn't work (because the gfx card really _is_ kind of old), I'm mostly confused why I'm not getting a defined error message.

Comment: If the driver is reset, the error condition should be exposed in the return value of [`Present`](http://slimdx.org/docs/html/M_SlimDX_DXGI_SwapChain_Present.htm), which you're currently ignoring.  The returned `result.code` should be one of the [DXGI error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509553(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Well, I'm later getting an error about a removed device (on the next call after present), but I'd rather get an error _before_ the driver gets into a condition that requires a reset.

Comment: Device-removed errors, and in particular driver internal errors (which it looks like here) are generally not possible to anticipate, so there's no way to know something bad is happening before the driver requires a reset.  From the system's perspective, everything's fine until suddenly it's not.  The system reports this to the app as soon as it knows and the app calls an API capable of returning an error code.  Often this is `Present` because for performance reasons the GPU runs asynchronously from the CPU, and `Present` is one of the few times a flush is required.

Comment: If you want to know as soon as reset happens, after every API call you can insert a call to [`Flush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476425(v=vs.85).aspx) to force a flush, followed by [`GetDeviceRemovedReason`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476526(v=vs.85).aspx) to check the state of the device (or whatever the SlimDx mapping is), but this will severely impact performance.